# Cannot find MSVCP140D_APP.dll

Tags: c++, opengl, dll

I am trying to make a simple rendering engine using opengl & freeglut. I am doing the rendering engine part in a seperate c++ project under the same solution and compiling it as a DLL, then using it in the "main" engine project.

I am having some trouble when I try to initialize the rendering engine. It complains about not being able to find MSVCP140D_APP.dll and VCRUNTIME140D_APP.dll

I know these dll's are related to microsoft visual C++ redist package, but I do have the very newest version installed. Could this be something wrong with my project properties on my Rendering Project?
[Image of solution setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tTlp.png)

Comment: Those files are not part of the redist packages as they are the debugging versions.

Comment: Oh. So I have to get them eslewhere and have them as a seperate file in the build path?

Comment: @Sillydan: No, they're normally used when you're debugging inside Visual Studio, and Visual Studio obviously knows about them.

Comment: @MSalters How come I get the error though? I have tried to reinstall the redist packages, but I still get the error. Could it be a linker issue?

Comment: @Sillydan: The redist packages are the **release** DLL's, as Richard said. So obviously that won't help you get debug DLL's. Are you debugging within Visual Studio 2015 when this happens? Also, the usual tool for diagnosing DLL issues is still Dependency Walker.

Comment: Ah. That explains it.
Debugging within visual studio? Yes. I am. I'll take a look at Dependency Walker, thanks :)