# Debugging Qt in visual studio, msvcp140d_app.dll is missing

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2017

I'm new to `Qt`, but have been working with *Visual studio* for *C/C++* development for a few years.  Now I'm trying to build a `GUI` for my project.  I installed `Qt` `5.11.0` and the `Qt` VS Tools on both my work computer and home PC.  At work I can build and run my project with the VS debugger, however on my home system I can build but can't run either with VS debugger or simply launching the app.  I tried in release and it runs fine.

The `error` I'm getting is :

> The code execution cannot proceed because VCRUNTIME140D_APP.dll was not found.

I get `4` of these, the first two want VCRUNTIME, the second two want `MSVCP140D_APP.dll`.

Solutions I've tried so far :

1. Uninstalled Win SDK and reinstalled
2. Uninstalled VS2017 and SDK and reinstalled
3. Searched System32, SysWOW64 and VS install directories - found `msvcp140d.dll` and `vcruntime140d.dll`, but no `_app.dlls`

Does anyone know what these are included with and where to get them?  I can't figure out why I have them on my work computer but not at home.  I have the same VS updates, same Qt version, and SDK on both systems.

Using :

- Visual Studio 2017 v15.7.1
- Qt 5.11.0 - msvc2017_64

I suppose I can just copy the `.dll's` from my work pc and drop them in the appropriate locations on the other, but I'd like to know what they should have been installed with so I can have the same setup on both systems.

Edit:
I also tried changing the platform toolset to VS2015 with Qt versions msvc2015_64 and winrt_x64_msvc2015

I found [this post concerning the same missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40255796/cannot-find-msvcp140d-app-dll) `_app.dll` files.  There wasn't any answer there, which is why I tried reinstalling the SDK in the hope the missing files were included there.

Edit 2:
I just scanned my entire system at work and it turns out that I don't have the missing `.dll` there either.  That tells me that there is a difference in the project properties or configuration between the two.  I use git for source control, and I am currently the only contributor to this project.  When I try to build and run just the example from the getting started guide I have the same problem at home with missing `_app.dll` files, however it works fine at work.  I'm totally confused now, and any hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

After trying for a couple of hours making new solutions etc. I decided to delete the entire build folder and put fresh copies of all the dependencies into it.  My project now runs fine in debugging mode.

I'm fairly certain that when I originally copied the Qt `.dll` files into it I must have grabbed them from one of the winrt folders rather than the msvc2017_64 folder.  To test I replaced the working `.dll` files with those from the winrt_x64_msvc2017 folder and sure enough the same errors again.  So, this was a dumb mistake on my part, but hopefully it'll save someone else a lot of hair-pulling in the future.

Comment: Great question with great answer!!