# Missing Qt dll when debugging the Qt project with Visual Studio 2022 17.6.5

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

My project worked pretty well (with Visual Studio 2022) before I upgraded the VS on to 17.6.5.

[image]

It continuously poped this missing Qt dll dialog when I debug it runing within Visual Studio. I know I can just copy these dlls to my project folder to make the debug work. But, once I didn't have to do that before I upgraded the VS.

The project can compile, just can't be debugged.

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50356348/debugging-qt-in-visual-studio-msvcp140d-app-dll-is-missing), cleaning all the output files, still not working.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

It works for me by just reinstalling the `Qt Visual Tools` -- actually I just disabled and reenabled it.